# How to determine the number of replicas of scaled service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that exposes 2 services, a master service and a slave service.  I want to be able to scale the slave service to some number of instances using

```
docker-compose up --scale slave=N
```

However, one of the options I must specify on command run in the master service is the number of slave instances to expect.  E.g. If I scale slave=10, I need to set --num-slaves=10 in the command on the master service.

Is there a way to determine the number of instances of a given service either from the docker-compose file itself, or from a customized entrypoint shellscript?

The problem I'm facing is that since there is no way I've yet found to specify the number of scaled instances from within the docker-compose file format itself, I'm relying on the person running the command to enter the scale factor consistently and to have that value align with the value I need to tell the master node to expect.  And trusting users to do the right thing is a recipe for disaster.  If I could continue to let the user specify the scale value on the command line, I need a way to determine what that value is at runtime.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not asking how to scale a service, but given that a service has already been scaled, e.g. --scale slave=N, how can I determine from "master" the number N, so that I can use that number in the command-line args for the executable run in the master command.  E.g. If I run docker-compose with --scale slave=3, master's command needs to look something like `/usr/bin/master-process --num-slaves 3`

Comment: One possible answer, which I'm not very keen on, is to look at the DNS records, e.g. `nslookup slave | grep Address | wc -l`.  That seems to give the correct number of instances, but is prone to errors, and I don't know if that is going to be reliable.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way to define replicas for docker compose. **IT ONLY WORKS FOR DOCKER SWARM** The documentation specifies it [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/)

***Tip: Alternatively, in Compose file version 3.x, you can specify replicas under the deploy key as part of a service configuration for Swarm mode. The deploy key and its sub-options (including replicas) only works with the docker stack deploy command, not docker-compose up or docker-compose run.***

So if you have the deploy section in the yaml, but run it with docker-compose, then it will not take any effect.

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  alpine1:
    image: alpine
    container_name: alpine1
    command: ["/bin/sleep", "10000"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
  alpine2:
    image: alpine
    container_name: alpine2
    command: ["/bin/sleep", "10000"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
```

So the only way to scale up in docker compose is by running the scale command manually.

```
docker-compose scale alpine1=3
```

**Note** I had a job in which they loved docker-compose so we had bash scripts to perform operations such as the ones you describe. So for example we would have something like `./controller-app.sh scale test_service=10` and it would run `docker-compose scale test_service=10`

**UPDATE**
To check the number of replicas you can mount the docker socket into your container. Then run `docker ps --format {{ .Names }} | grep $YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME`.

Here is how you would mount the socket.

```
docker run -v  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it alpine sh
```

Install docker

```
apk update
apk add docker
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, this does not answer the original question, which was, given that I scale a service, how can another service determine the number of instances of the scaled service.

Comment: Well as the other guy said it is not clear. But now that you mention it of course it is possible. Dirty practice, would not do it ever in prod, but possible.